# String from bufferedReader to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, client-server, bufferedreader

I have a local server-class, which sends two String messages ("The first message", "The second message") to client-class. 
In client-class I'd like to put them into an ArrayList
code from  BufferedReader and then print.

```
void go () throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4242);
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
       list.add(reader.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

But all that I get - is a line "null"
What's wrong with it?
I’ll be very grateful for any help

Comment: The code given will not print "null" as a result, ever. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ciprianoss is correct but also in the loop

```
while (reader.readLine() != null) {
   list.add(reader.readLine());
}
```

You are reading from the file TWICE

Once in the while and the again just before you add.

```
list.add(reader.readLine());
```

as ciprianoss suggested

```
String line;
while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
   list.add(line);
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you do .readLine() it will no longer be in the buffer, change your while loop to:

```
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way should be using `bufferedReader.lines()`, which returns a stream:

```
public List<String> readerToList(final Reader reader) {
  try (final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
    return bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```